# SoundCloud API- Get current time and set current time when streaming

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

So I am streaming a sound with the SoundCloud api, and I'd like to know how to set the current time in the stream and get the current time in the stream. If the latter is not possible it doesn't really matter cause I can just use setInterval as a stopwatch kinda thing. So if I was using this:

```
SC.stream('/tracks/' + track.id, function(sound){
    sound.start();
}
```

I would want

```
sound.--method to get current time in sound--();
```

and

```
sound.--method to set current time in sound--();
```

Comment: is `getCurrentPosition` what you are looking for?

Comment: @gryzzly Actually that's not a method but as bnz suggested sound.position (Not a method) is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this could be something like this:

```
SC.stream("/tracks/" + track.id, { 
        autoPlay: true,
        whileplaying: function () {
            console.log(this.position);
            }       
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/wmm7agq5/

Set method here:

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#soundmanager-setposition